# Merging FirebaseDatabase Queries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I understand that a `Query` (`com.google.firebase.database`) object is like the equivalent of a `Cursor` (`android.database`) object.

So is it possible to merge two or more `Query` objects in some equivalent fashion that one can merge two or more `Cursor` objects?

I have searched through and don't seem to see any information about this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to create a single query that consists of multiple other queries.

The common approach is to execute each individual query separately, and then merge the results in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

Complex queries are not supported for FirebaseDatabase. You can find possible solution here [Firebase for complex query. A no go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672790/firebase-for-complex-query-a-no-go)